# How to use :not() in tailwind.css

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css

I recently started to give tailwind.css a try in my Nuxt project. so I needed to use `:not(:last-child)` pseudo-elements but I don't know how.

```
  <ul>
    <li
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="`item-${index}`"
      class="border-solid border-b border-black"
    >
      Item
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to add a border-bottom to all of the `<li>` except the last one.

I know Tailwind has [first](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#first-child-v1-1-0) & [last](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#last-child-v1-1-0) pseudo-class variant but I can't use them with `:not()`

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The answer is in the link to [`last` in the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants#last-child-v1-1-0), that you shared.

Just add `last:border-b-0` to all list items, and it will remove the `border-bottom` if it is the `last-child`.

```html
<ul>
  <li
    v-for="(item, index) in items"
    :key="`item-${index}`"
    class="border-solid border-b border-black last:border-b-0"
  >
    Item
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: isn't it a problem with efficiency? because we need to write 2 tailwind classes but in simple CSS we have so much more selector powers.

Comment: 1) Give it a try, inspect the list and you will notice that it is only applied to the last item. So no problem with efficiency.
2) That's the whole point with Tailwind: insted of writing CSS, you write classes in HTML.

Comment: also, you need to fix config 

  `variants: {
    extend: {
      margin: ['first', 'last']
    },
  },`

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 89):

You can use [Tailwind arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants):

```html
<li class="[&:not(:last-child)]:border border-sky-500">Item</li>
```

This is available since [Tailwind v3](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3).

Answer (score 2):

We could also do this by selecting the index number we want to edit

EXAMPLE: I will change the first one, and all the following should have a style

```
<div
    v-for="(item, i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :class="{ 'mx-0': i === 0, 'mx-4': i > 0 }"
>
</div>
```

so the FIRST element has an index from 0, and therefore we will have a margin x 0,

and all of the following would have margin x 4.