# Negate a condition in Tailwind css

Tags: css, css-selectors, tailwind-css, styling, tailwind-in-js

There is a list of elements where I want to apply a style for all the elements starting from the second one and another style for the first one.

To apply for the first one it's working `first-of-type:bg-red-500` but how to apply a style to the other ones?

It seems that `:not(first-of-type:bg-blue-500)` does not work.

Comment: For this specific use case, use the `last:` modifier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455473/how-to-use-not-in-tailwind-css

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible at this moment in Tailwind, see [pseudo class reference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#pseudo-class-reference) for a list possible variants.

In your specific case you might want to use `first` (or `first-of-type`) modifier [like that](https://play.tailwindcss.com/J7ckUwyH97):

```
<div>
  <div class="first:bg-blue-500 bg-red-500">First</div>
  <div class="first:bg-blue-500 bg-red-500">Second</div>
  <div class="first:bg-blue-500 bg-red-500">Third</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively what you can do is to apply needed styles through js by looking at the index of the element, for example if you have list of elements in React:

```
      <div>
        {list.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={index === 0 ? 'bg-blue-500' : 'bg-red-500'}
          >
            {
              // ...
            }
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using the index to selectively apply styles is a very good idea.